# Convert observable to list

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am using RxJava.

I have an `Observable<T>`. How do I convert it to `List<T>`?

Seems to be a simple operation, but I couldn't find it anywhere on the net.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [toList()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#tolist) or [toSortedList()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#tosortedlist) . For e.g.

```
observable.toList(myObservable)
          .subscribe({ myListOfSomething -> do something useful with the list });
```

Comment: This doesn't convert it to a list. This is basically the same as if I have called `subscribe`.

Comment: also note that toList() only creates the list when the sequence completes, so not useful for a long running stream

Answer (score 80):

```java
List<T> myList = myObservable.toList().toBlocking().single();
```

Comment: it will result in blocking , not asyn

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt - did the `toBlocking` call give it away? (The question doesn't ask for it to be asynchronous)

Answer (score 13):

RxJava 2+:

```
List<T> = theObservarale
             .toList()
             .blockingGet();
```

Comment: this returns only 1 size, kindly check my question here please : https://stackoverflow.com/q/49562033/3974048

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `collect` operator:

```
    ArrayList list = observable.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add)
                               .toBlocking()
                               .single();
```

With `collect`, you can choose which type of `Collection` you prefer and perform an additional operation on the item before adding it to the list.

Comment: The collect could be written using method references as `collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add)`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, missed the use of method references here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert observable to list in any idiomatic way, because a list isn't really a type that fits in with Rx.

If you want to populate a list with the events from a observable stream you need to basically create a list and add the items within a `Subscribe` method like so (C#):

```
IObservable<EventType> myObservable = ...;
var list = new List<EventType>();
myObservable.Subscribe(evt => list.Add(evt));
```

The `ToList`-style operators only provide a list once the stream completes (as an `IObservable<List<T>>`), so that isnt useful in scenarios where you have a long-lived stream or you want to see values before the stream completes.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Observable.just("this", "is", "how", "you", "do", "it")
            .lift(customToList())
            .subscribe(strings -> System.out.println(String.join(" ", strings)));

}

public static <T> ObservableOperator<List<T>, T> customToList() {

    return observer -> new DisposableObserver<T>() {

        ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            arrayList.add(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            observer.onError(throwable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            observer.onNext(arrayList);
            observer.onComplete();
        }
    };
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late answer, hope it helps somebody in future.

There is an operator `collectInto()`. I would suggest everyone to not use `blocking()` (unless in a test case) as you completely loose the purpose of async events in `Rxchains`. Try to chain your operations as much as possible

```
Completable setList(List<Integer> newIntegerList, Observable<Integer> observable){
   return observable.collectInto(newIntegerList, List::add).ignoreElement();
}

 // Can call this method
 Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
 setList(list, observable);
```

You save the hassle of using `blocking()` in this case.

Answer (score -11):

Found it myself

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(Observable<T> observable) {
    final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    observable.toBlocking().forEach(new Action1<T>() {
        @Override
        public void call(T t) {
            list.add(t);
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of an anti-pattern. Use `Observable.toList()` instead, and make sure that the `Observable` is not infinite or you will have problems.

Comment: As Thomas sayed, you may want to reconsider accepting this one, that's not the way to do it.